# Assign a variable inside a Block to a variable outside a Block

Tags: objective-c, compiler-errors, objective-c-blocks

I'm getting an error

> Variable is not assignable (missing __block type specifier)

on the line `aPerson = participant;`. How can I make sure the block can access the `aPerson` variable and the `aPerson` variable can be returned?

```
Person *aPerson = nil;

[participants enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {   
    Person *participant = (Person*)obj;

    if ([participant.gender isEqualToString:@"M"]) {
        aPerson = participant;
        *stop = YES;
    }
}];

return aPerson;
```

Answer (score 827, accepted):

You need to use this line of code to resolve your problem:

```
__block Person *aPerson = nil;
```

For more details, please refer to this tutorial: [Blocks and Variables](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html)

Comment: Please note that `__block` is prefixed with **two** underscores.

Comment: using `__block` my error gone, but value is not retaining out of block. Any help here

Comment: The block is called well after where it looks like it should be called, in other words, blocks don't run 'right away'.

Comment: If blocks don't run RIGHT AWAY then this should not be accepted answer as that makes it a huge deal breaker.

Comment: This answer is correct with respect to posted question, feel free to post another question if you have a different scenario in mind.

Answer (score 43):

Just a reminder of a mistake I made myself too, the

```
 __block
```

declaration must be done when first declaring the variable, that is, OUTSIDE of the block, not inside of it. This should resolve problems mentioned in the comments about the variable not retaining its value outside of the block.

Answer (score 19):

Just use the `__block` prefix to declare and assign any type of variable inside a block.

For example:

```
__block Person *aPerson = nil;

__block NSString *name = nil;
```

Answer (score 11):

To assign  a variable inside block which outside of block always use __block specifier before that variable your code should be like this:-

```
__block Person *aPerson = nil;
```

Answer (score 10):

```
__block Person *aPerson = nil;
```

Answer (score 4):

When I saw the same error, I tried to resolve it like:

```
   __block CGFloat docHeight = 0.0;


    [self evaluateJavaScript:@"document.height" completionHandler:^(id height, NSError *error) {
        //height
        NSLog(@"=========>document.height:@%@",height);
        docHeight = [height floatValue];
    }];
```

and its working fine

Just add  "**__block**"  before Variable.

Answer (score 3):

Try `__weak` if you get any warning regarding retain cycle else use `__block`

```
Person *strongPerson = [Person new];
__weak Person *weakPerson = person;
```

Now you can refer **`weakPerson`** object inside block.

Answer (score 3):

yes block are the most used functionality , so in order to avoid the retain cycle we should avoid using the strong variable,including self  inside the block, inspite use the _weak or weakself.