# Use variable with in block

Tags: objective-c-blocks

I am using some public APIs for displaying images where i am using following code to show image full screen and once full screen is closed i want to call **RateImage:** method with **imgID**

```
__block NSString *imgID = _img.ImageID;
[cell.imageView setupImageViewerWithImageURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strImageURL] onOpen:^{
    NSLog(@"Open");
} onClose:^{
    [MyAppDelegate RateImage:imgID];
}];
```

I dont know for some reason my application crashes.

**error:** address doesn't contain a section that points to a section in a object file

I have been through [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962721/how-to-assign-a-variable-inside-a-block-to-a-variable-outside-a-block)

can any one tell how to pass value with in block?

Comment: Is it the onClose causing the crash? i.e if you remove [MyAppDelegate RateImage:imgID]; does it run fine?

Comment: @sbarow yes, if i remove statement [MyAppDelegate RateImage:imgID]; from onClose it runes fine. it crashes when i am using imgID.

Comment: If you call  [MyAppDelegate RateImage:imgID]; outside of the block does it still crash? Just make a false id to test.

Comment: there's no point in using `__block` here

Comment: are you using MRC or ARC?

Comment: @newacct I am using ARC. can you please clarify on your comment "there's no point in using __block here"...!

Comment: @sbarow if i use [MyAppDelegate RateImage:@"10"]; out side of the block it works fine.

Comment: Please can you post the code for RateImage, the reason there is no need for __block is that you are not modifying the imgID object.

Comment: @iCoder86: it's because you are not assigning to the `imgID` variable anywhere

Comment: My only requirement is to pass imgID to RateImage: function in onColse block, but anyhow when i try to access imgID within the onClose section my app crashes. The function RateImage: of MyAppDelegate is just to popup rating view on screen.