# afnetworking get json data out from response

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, afnetworking

I am trying to extract data(just a string) from request and set it to the NSString. I tried it in many way but it is not working. If anyone can point out my mistake, it will be very helpful for me.

json data

```
{
    "status": 1,
    "key": "1e39248f4a5e05153dc376a"
}
```

My code

```
NSString *key;
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

    NSDictionary *params = @ {@"app_token" :APP_TOKEN};

    [manager POST:GET_USER_KEY_URL parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSDictionary* response = (NSDictionary*) responseObject;
        key=[response valueForKey:@"key"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue:(key) forKey:USER_KEY];
        NSLog(@"NEW KEY Request: %@", key);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"NEW KEY Request error: %@", error);
    }];
```

Just want to assign response "key" data and store it on the NSString *key;

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Any error? What does NSLog say?

Comment: for this line

key=[response valueForKey:@"key"];

Variable is not assignable (missing __block type specifier)

Comment: Are you sure you get that JSON back ? What is the content of response or responseObject?

Comment: yes. with out that line log print data

Comment: can you try objectForKey instead of valueForKey?  and I am not sure what do you mean by 'without that line log print data'. When you log response you get that JSON from above?

Comment: You have declared the variable `key` outside of the block. You need to add `__block` infront of `NSString *key;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have declared the variable key outside of the block. You need to add `__block` infront of `NSString *key;`

To assign a variable outside a block you have to remember the `__block` specifier.

Related question:
[Assign a variable inside a Block to a variable outside a Block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962721/assign-a-variable-inside-a-block-to-a-variable-outside-a-block)