# How to access a variable inside the block of id type in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

After searching for this type of error:

> Variable is not assignable (missing __block type specifier)

I found the following solution [Assign a variable inside a Block to a variable outside a Block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962721/assign-a-variable-inside-a-block-to-a-variable-outside-a-block) and after I read about the [__block](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH6-SW6) I could not benefit from the accepted answer and my code is different scenario.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
NSDictionary *strongUser = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
__block  NSDictionary *user = strongUser;

NSMutableDictionary* parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[parameters setValue:@"id, name, email" forKey:@"fields"]; 
[[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:parameters]
    startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        user = result;
}];

NSLog(@"%@",user);
```

`NSLog` print nothing

What I want is to given the result value to extern variable outside the block.

[image]

Comment: What about your completion handler, have it finished?

Comment: my completion handler finished

Comment: Ok, and 'result' parameter is what you want?

Comment: I think you're confused about the order things will run in asynchronous code. You should move all the code below your API call into a separate method that you call from your completion block. Pass the result into that method.

Comment: yes you are right now i get it

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `__block NSDictionary *strongUser`.  I'm concerned that the pointer `user` still exists inside the block, but the underlying variable to which it is pointing may no longer be accessible.  For example:

```
__block NSDictionary *strongUser = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];

NSMutableDictionary* parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[parameters setValue:@"id, name, email" forKey:@"fields"]; 
[[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:parameters]
 startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
 {
     strongUser = result;
 }];
```

Comment: can u provide a detailed answer ?

Comment: i tried your solution same problem persist

Answer (score 0):

Add the following *inside* your block:

```
NSLog(@"Doing assignment inside the block");
```

Then run your code.

The answer to your question will be obvious.

HTH

Comment: i could not understand what you are trying to say

Comment: In what order do the two log statements print when you run your code?

Comment: the log outside the block run before the inside the block i know that but i want a solution

Comment: Solution - use property, not local variable. Or wait async block to be finished.

Comment: That is the nature of asynchronous programming. There are various ways to handle the issue. You can call a completion/continuation block from within you block, passing on the result; you can use semaphores to wait for completion; etc., etc. You need to read up on asynchronous design and pick a solution which suits your scenario. HTH

Comment: @EvgenyKarkan - a property won't directly help with the problem, which is trying to access the result before it is assigned.

Comment: @CRD - yep, good point, but at least 'strongUser' data will be visible from the class scope. Maybe it will be enouth for topic starter.

Answer (score 0):

You run your code async, and your log evaluates before completion handler.
Add your log directly inside completion handler's scope.

```
NSDictionary *strongUser = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
__block  NSDictionary *user = strongUser;

NSMutableDictionary* parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[parameters setValue:@"id, name, email" forKey:@"fields"]; 
[[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:parameters]
 startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
 {
     user = result;

     NSLog(@"%@",user);
 }];
```

Comment: yes already read about this on https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH6-SW6 but how i can solve my problem

Comment: See my updated code snippet.

Comment: the log inside the block give me the result but what i want to access those value outside the block

Comment: You can access to it only after completion handler did finished, because 'startWithCompletionHandler' runs asynchronously. Try to create 'strongUser' not as local variable but as property - so it will be visible in your class scope.

Answer (score 0):

You have a local variable strongUser, it means that when this scope(function) will be finished, your local variable strongUser will be deallocated - so when your block works __block variavle user is alive but it points to unexist object.

The easy wasy to implement it right is to create a property with lazy setter:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *strongUser;

- (NSDictionary *)strongUser {
    if (!_strongUser) {
        _strongUser = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
    }
    return _strongUser;
}
```

And call it with selfinside block:

```
    NSMutableDictionary* parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [parameters setValue:@"id, name, email" forKey:@"fields"];

    [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me"parameters:parameters]
 startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
     self.strongUser = result;  
     NSLog(@"%@",self.strongUser);  
     }];
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: same problem persist :S

Comment: @ZakariaDarwish you won't get the value of result in NSLog on the last row, because it works earlier than completion block. The value of the result will be setted in strongUser after finish  completion.

Comment: can you tell me how to know when the completion will be finished

Comment: it is a scope where this row works: self_.strongUser = result;

Comment: i will update the code maybe my question will be more clear

Comment: I think you should read something like this: http://www.cognitivedesign.com/papers/understanding-blocks-in-ios.html

Comment: I edited my answer, you can keep working inside block complition and do what you need with self.strongUser there.